# Cómo descontar 45 mints de duración en hojas de cálculo de Google cuando pase por las 12:30pm

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La duración es una simple diferencia, al pasar las 12:30pm necesito que descuente 45 mints pero.. ¿Cómo detecto que haya pasado las 12:30pm? usando Google App script?

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de cómo deberían quedar los resultados?

Comment: Claro, acabo de modificar la imagen de mi pregunta. En la Fila N° 1 no hay descuento de tiempo sin embargo en el item 2 se descuentan 45 minutos por el refrigerio del empleado, esto solo ocurre si entre el inicio y el fin de la actividad pasan las 12:30pm porque el refrigerio es de 12:30pm a 1:15pm. gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver, lo primero, etiquetaste como Excel y Macros esta pregunta, cuando no tiene nada que ver. Hojas de cálculo de Google, si bien es similar a Excel, son dos entornos diferentes. Lo digo para el futuro, para que etiquetes bien las preguntas.

Lo segundo, yo he hecho un ejemplo sencillo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi fórmula en la celda D2 es:

```
=SI(C2<HORANUMERO("12:30:00");C2-B2;C2-B2-HORANUMERO("00:45:00"))
```

La función `HORANUMERO` nos permite especificar una hora, y que Google Sheets devuelva el valor numérico decimal de dicha hora. Así que combinando esa función con un simple `SI` entonces podemos comprobar si la hora de inicio es menor que las `12:30:00` y actuar en consecuencia.

Espero que puedas adaptarlo a tus necesidades.

Comment: Elier muchas gracias, desconocía la función horanumero() y me estaba complicando. En serio muchísimas gracias.

Psdt. El portal no me aceptaba la etiqueta de "Hojas de cálculo de Google".